# Crear condicion para 'estatus'

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo esta función:

```
public function referenciaDuplicada($referencia , $compra_id = null){
    if( $compra_id ){
        return Compra::where('referencia',$referencia)->where('id','!=',$compra_id)->count();
    }
    return Compra::where('referencia',$referencia)->count();
}
```

Y la estoy usando para esta validación:

```
public function update(UpdateRequest $request){

    $subotal_articulos = $this->subotalArticulos($request->articulos);
    $referencia_duplicada = $this->referenciaDuplicada($request->orden_compra['referencia'],$request->orden_compra['po_id']);
    $remision_duplicada = $this->remisionDuplicada($request->orden_compra['remision'],$request->orden_compra['po_id']);

    if( $referencia_duplicada > 0 ){
        return response()->json(['errors' =>
            ['El número de Referencia ya existe. Por favor, ingrese una nueva Referencia.'],
            'data' => null
        ], 422);
    }
```

Si **Compra** se cancela, el dato 'referencia' debería poder usarse para crear una nueva **Compra**, sin embargo, no se como hacer agregar esa validación en el código de arriba.

Necesito ayuda para agregar esa validación a mi código, para de esta forma permita al usuario usar una 'referencia' existente, siempre y cuando **Compra** este en 'estatus' de 'aprobado'.

Gracias!

Comment: Entonces, la validación no debe dejar tomar referencias de las compras que no están en aprobado, cierto?

Comment: Cierto, pero ya lo resolví! Muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberías publicar tu solución y marcarla como aceptada así la pregunta se entiende como resuelta